Lattice Machxo3D FPGA Can't program feature row using spi
I'm trying to program the feature row of a Lattice Machxo3D using sspi, but no success. When I'm reading back the feature row, I get 0s.
I'm able to program the other sectors of the flash properly.
Here are the instructions that I'm sending:

ISC_ENABLE (0xC6)
LSC_INIT_ADDRESS (0x46)
LSC_READ_STATUS_0 (0x3C)
LSC_READ_STATUS_1 (0x3D)
LSC_PROG_FEATURE (0xE4)
LSC_READ_FEATURE (0xE7)
ISC_PROGRAM_DONE (0x5E)   //Since the read doesn't give me the data that I wrote... I'm not really calling it.
REFRESH (0x79)  //Same thing

The opcodes and the flow are taken from the documentation FPGA-TN-02119-1.4 (Using Hardened Control Functions...) and FPGA-TN-02069-1.7 (Programming and Configuration User Guide).
When reading the status registers, the values seem valid.
So after spending a lot of time reading the documentation, I can't seem to find what I'm missing.
Is it possible to do it?
Why am I not reading back what I wrote?
Thanks

does you code abide the required delays? Your sequences seems to miss "Erase CFG/UFM/FR (0x0E)", intentionally? You omitted the operands. Likelyhood to find an error is higher if you provide the full sequence/program flow. Ideally as an minimal reproducable example.
